# dynamics 365 API 9.1 associate contact to opportunity

Tags: python, api, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

We are using https://github.com/dangoscomb/pydynamics in Python to connect to our Dynamics 365 org.

We can create, select, update our entity sets.

```
import pydynamics
from pydynamics.client import Client
from pydynamics.querybuilder import QueryBuilder
token = tokenres.json()['access_token']
pdc = Client(token, endpoint=CREDENTIALS['resource'] + CREDENTIALS['api_base_url'] )

#======update contact (works fine) =========
q = QueryBuilder('contacts').guid('2bcd88c7-c295-ea11-a811-000d3a6546e3').\
    data({'firstname': 'ChangedFirstName'})
pdc.update(q)
```

For associating entities we followed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/associate-disassociate-entities-using-web-api

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)/opportunity_customer_accounts/$ref HTTP/1.1   
Content-Type: application/json   
Accept: application/json   
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0   
OData-Version: 4.0  

{  
"@odata.id":"[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/opportunities(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)"  
}
```

If we do it accordingly, we get errors that the json is invalid!

```
print(js)
{'@odata.id': '<ORG>/api/data/v9.1/opportunities(4585df90-4aa3-ea11-a812-000d3a6546e3)'}

import requests
query = 'contacts(ab906e8c-4aa3-ea11-a812-000d3a65473c)/opportunity_customer_contacts/$ref'
resp=requests.post(endpoint + query, headers=headers, data=js)
resp.json()
```

```
{'error': {'code': '0x0',
  'message': 'An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.\r\n
```

Might there be a problem with this "@odata.id" ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. Microsofts documentation is not very precise. They write

```
{  
 "customerid_account@odata.bind":"[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)"  
}
```

It does NOT need the "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0" Part.

Solution:

```
q = QueryBuilder('opportunities').guid(opport_guid).\
    data({  "customerid_contact@odata.bind":  f"/contacts({contact_guid})"   })
DynamicsClient.update(q)
```

Comment: what is [Organization URI] . From where do I get this. I have dynamics 365 account and stuff etc

Comment: It's the first part of the URL: `https://orgfe7564a7.crm4.dynamics.com/`